# How to over-ride the default templates provided by Django-allauth?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

I created **myapp/templates/account/base.html** and **myapp/templates/account/login.html**, so I think that should have changed the templates. But going to /account/login still loads the default template and not my new one. How do I actually over-ride them then?

I have this in my **settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                # `allauth` needs this from django
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your root dir to the `DIRS` setting:

```
'DIRS': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I override them by placing them in my `account` and/or `socialaccount` in the root of my template folder. Optionally with a parent folder called `allauth`

your structure would look something like:

- templates

  - account
  - socialaccount

or

- templates

  - allauth

    - account
    - socialaccount

The original templates can be found at https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates